# Resetting CSS values after velocity("stop", true) before starting new animation

Tags: jquery, transform, containers, window-resize, velocity.js

for explanation purposes only. The actual code looks different.

I've got the image to scroll nicely within the container. Up and down in a loop. Looks great. BUT, if I change the height of the container (invoked by my media query), then the calculations are thrown out of sync. I want to reset the scrolling, but it doesn't work. I've also tried doing something like scrollingImage.css({transform: 'translateY(0px)'}); after stopping the animation and before starting it again on resize, but with no luck. If I reload the page in the new size (so the container is 300 instead of 500) it works great. But not if it happens on the fly on browser resize. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  /********** THE CSS **********/
  .container{
    background-color: red;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .container img{
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 400px) {
    .container{
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
    }
  }


  /********** THE HTML **********/
  <div class="container">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/Rope_swing_really_tall_Summit_NJ.jpg"/>
  </div>


  /********** THE JAVASCRIPT (jquery and velocity already loaded) **********/
  function enableScrollingContent() {
    var container = $('.container');
    var scrollingImage = container.find('img');
    scrollingImage.velocity("stop", true);
    var offsetY = -scrollingImage.height() + (container.height());
    scrollingImage.velocity({ translateY: offsetY }, { duration: 5000, loop: true });
  }
  enableScrollingContent();
  $(window).resize(enableScrollingContent);
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you could put this into a jsFiddle example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qnLe78o0/1/

Comment: try resizing the browser window. It works "ok", but it looks like the stop,true have no effect. The animation goes slower and slower. I would like for it to simply reset on resize so that it restarts from 0 and runs just as if the page was reloaded. I mean if the animation would continue from where it left of and the code updated to adjust the height according to the new image height, then great. But as a minimum viable solution, it needs to be as smooth, and no red showing ever.